# Amazon Lex PostText operation not returning confidence scores

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I am using the AWS SDK for JavaScript in Node.js.

Calling the `PostText` operation does not seem to return the confidence scores even though I have configured the bot to enable accuracy improvements, set the confidence threshold and published it on the AWS console.

Additionally calling the `PutBot` operation with the `enableModelImprovements` and `nluIntentConfidenceThreshold` parameters will throw the following errors:

```
UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'enableModelImprovements' found in params
UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'nluIntentConfidenceThreshold' found in params
```

On the AWS console itself, the confidence scores are returned. However, this is not the case when using the sdk for JavaScript.

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I can see the sentiment score, but intent confidence doesn't show in nodejs (didn't try it in javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update your aws-sdk to the latest version then you will be able get confidence scores as well.
Please run this command

npm install aws-sdk@2.780.0